# How to fill by color 3rd triangle (Python, Turtle)

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Hi guys I have a problem
I need to create nested triangles and fill by any different color 3rd triangle
But i can't do this

```
from turtle import *
speed(100)

number_of_shapes = 5

for shape in range(1, number_of_shapes + 1):
    # Draw A Triangle
    forward(shape * 10)
    for i in range(2):
        left(120)
        forward(shape * 20)
    left(120)
    forward(shape * 10)
    if i == 3: 
      pencolor('red')
      pensize(10)
    else:
        pencolor('black') 
        pensize(1)

    right(90)
    penup()
    forward(7)
    pendown()
    left(90)

done()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem seems to be you're testing the wrong variable:

```
if i == 3:
```

where `i` is an iteration variable of an unrelated previous loop.  What you want to test is `shape`, the iteration variable of the loop you're in.

It's not clear what you're trying to draw, here's my best guess based on your description:

```
from turtle import *

number_of_shapes = 5

speed('fastest')
fillcolor(bgcolor())

for shape in range(number_of_shapes, 0, -1):
    if shape == 3:
        fillcolor('red')

    begin_fill()

    forward(shape * 10)
    for _ in range(3):
        left(120)
        forward(shape * 20)

    backward(shape * 10)

    end_fill()

    if shape == 3:
        fillcolor(bgcolor())

    left(90)
    penup()
    forward(5.54)
    pendown()
    right(90)

hideturtle()

done()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for explanation and your help